# Get the position of div on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hi Guys,**

I'm not so good with jQuery and javascript.
I will make a script that take the position of my div and when it's on the top of the page it make something.

**Example**:

I have a menu. When i scroll the page and my div arrive at the top (or better at 100/200px from top), something in my menu changes...

I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: A picture to describe what you are trying to do would be helpful. Also post some code of what you have tried.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the **offset** of your div element to how far down the page the user has **scrolled**.

The **$(window).scrollTop()** function get you how far the user has scrolled down, i.e :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var yourDiv = $("#theIdOfYourDiv");
  var window_offset = yourDiv.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
  if ( window_offset < 100 )
  {
  // do what you want
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. A simple script that solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the jQuery offset() scrollTop() and scroll() methods to achieve this.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Offset returns the pixel value of the elements from the top of the page. Run this on scroll, and you can detect when the element is 100px, or 200px from the top.

Here is an example of running offset() and scrollTop() on window.scroll(), and adding/removing classes when the element has reached the top of this page. In this example, I am fixing the $mainMenuBar to the top of the page when the user scrolls past it, and un-fixing it when the user scroll back up past it.

```
   // declare vars
    var $window = $(window),
        $mainMenuBar = $('.anchor-tabs'),
        $mainMenuBarAnchor = $('.anchor-tabs-anchor');

    // run on every pixel scroll
    $window.scroll(function() {
        var window_top = $window.scrollTop();
        var div_top = $mainMenuBarAnchor.offset().top;
        if (window_top > div_top) {
            // Make the div sticky.
            $mainMenuBar.addClass('fixed-top');
            $mainMenuBarAnchor.height($mainMenuBar.height());
        }
        else {
            // Unstick the div
            $mainMenuBar.removeClass('fixed-top');
            $mainMenuBarAnchor.height(0);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.